# Mapping of Keys using dictionary and lists in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, transformation

I have a *list of list of dictionaries* like below:

```
ini_dict = [[
       {'nikhil': 1, 'vashu': 5, 'manjeet': 10, 'akshat': 16}, 
       {'nikhil': 1, 'vashu': 5, 'manjeet': 10, 'akshat': 15}
]]
```

### Step 1: Reduce one level

I have modified and reduced one level like below:

```
mod = []
for i in ini_dict:
    for j in i:
        mod.append({item: values for item, values in j.items()})
```

This gives me output as below:

```
[
   {'nikhil': 1, 'vashu': 5, 'manjeet': 10, 'akshat': 15}, 
   {'nikhil': 1, 'vashu': 5, 'manjeet': 10, 'akshat': 15}
]
```

### Step 2: Replace the keys with values from another dict

Now, I have another set of *keys dictionary* `result_dict1`
where I use the keys (here in lowercase) to replace the keys from above data `mod` with related values (here in uppercase).

```
result_dict1 = {
   "nikhil": "Nikhil",
   "vashu": "Vashu",
   "manjeet": "Manjeet",
   "akshat": "Akshat"
}
```

#### Code I tried

Now, I have tried the below code but it's not giving me the output I need:

```
final = []
for j, k in result_dict1.items():
    for i in mod:
        for x, y in i.items():
            final += [{k: y}]
```

**Output**:

```
[{'Nikhil': 1}, {'Nikhil': 5}, {'Nikhil': 10}, {'Nikhil': 15}, {'Nikhil': 1}, {'Nikhil': 5}, {'Nikhil': 10}, {'Nikhil': 15}, {'Vashu': 1}, {'Vashu': 5}, {'Vashu': 10}, {'Vashu': 15}, {'Vashu': 1}, {'Vashu': 5}, {'Vashu': 10}, {'Vashu': 15}, {'Manjeet': 1}, {'Manjeet': 5}, {'Manjeet': 10}, {'Manjeet': 15}, {'Manjeet': 1}, {'Manjeet': 5}, {'Manjeet': 10}, {'Manjeet': 15}, {'Akshat': 1}, {'Akshat': 5}, {'Akshat': 10}, {'Akshat': 15}, {'Akshat': 1}, {'Akshat': 5}, {'Akshat': 10}, {'Akshat': 15}]
```

#### Problem

Keys are replaced but the combination is `1:N`.

**Expected output**:

```
[
   {'Nikhil': 1, 'Vashu': 5, 'Manjeet': 10, 'Akshat': 15}, 
   {'Nikhil': 1, 'Vashu': 5, 'Manjeet': 10, 'Akshat': 15}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues

You were almost there:

- Step 1: works as expected
- Step 2: iterates over the key-mapping `result_dict1` instead over the `mod`

#### Fixed

I added comments where I

- removed the loop or added it back slightly modified
- introcuced an inner collection (dict) to keep the source separation

```py
ini_dict = [[
       {'nikhil': 1, 'vashu': 5, 'manjeet': 10, 'akshat': 16}, 
       {'nikhil': 1, 'vashu': 5, 'manjeet': 10, 'akshat': 15}
]]

# step 2:
mod = []
for i in ini_dict:
    for j in i:
        mod.append({item: values for item, values in j.items()}) 

print(f"step 1:\n{mod}")

# step 2:
result_dict1 = {
   "nikhil": "Nikhil",
   "vashu": "Vashu",
   "manjeet": "Manjeet",
   "akshat": "Akshat"
}  

final = []
# for j, k in result_dict1.items():
for i in mod:
    inner = {}  # collect inner separately
    for x, y in i.items():
        k = result_dict1[x]  # lookup in dict, instead for-loop
        # final += [{k: y}]
        inner[k] = y  # add to inner (not to final outer) !as dict-entry! (not as list)
    final.append(inner)  # keep separation
    
print(f"step 2:\n{final}")
```

Prints:

```
step 1:
[{'nikhil': 1, 'vashu': 5, 'manjeet': 10, 'akshat': 16}, {'nikhil': 1, 'vashu': 5, 'manjeet': 10, 'akshat': 15}]
step 2:
[{'Nikhil': 1, 'Vashu': 5, 'Manjeet': 10, 'Akshat': 16}, {'Nikhil': 1, 'Vashu': 5, 'Manjeet': 10, 'Akshat': 15}]
```

**Note:**
Your original outer for-loop `k for j, k in result_dict1.items()` can be rewritten as:

```
keys = [k for j, k in result_dict1.items() if j == x] # for-loop as list-comprehension with added conditional
k = keys[0]  # key expected as first element in resulting list
```

Pretty complicated.. plus, we expect to find the key, but what if the list `keys` is empty? Then `keys[0]` would raise `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Better we benefit from the dict here and simplify the lookup: `k = result_dict1[x]`

#### Advice: Naming helps

As far as I can see, the naming of variables can be improved.
Then maybe this *logical flaw* would have been recognized earlier.

For example see the `inner` is more meaningful than `i`. It can be read and understood like human language - without keeping a name-dictionary or mapping like "i: inner list or dictionary" in memory as additional cognitive load.

#### Fixed alternative

Compare the current implementation for *Step 2* with yours from **Step 1**:

```
mod = []
for i in ini_dict:
    for j in i:
        mod.append({item: values for item, values in j.items()}) 

print(f"step 1:\n{mod}")
```

We can **reuse the pattern** known as *dict comprehension* here too:

```
final = []
for i in mod:
    final.append({result_dict1[x]: values for x, values in i.items()})
    
print(f"step 2:\n{final}")
```

Benefits:

- visual resemblance can be identified as shape (even when zoomed-out to 10% in large files)
- it looks simpler because familiar (after we already understood step 1)
- easier recognize which parts are similar (to step 1) and where they differ (e.g. no nested level for-loop)

This is also called **code symmetry**. See e.g. Carlos Ble (2014): [Code Symmetry](https://www.carlosble.com/2014/05/code-symmetry/)

Comment: Oh forgot to keep separation of (two) lists as in `mod`.. currently the result is _flattened_   Will fix in a few hours.

Comment: Fixed and updated. Took the opportunity to illustrate how naming helps to reduce cognitive load and ease comprehension, even can prevent bugs.

Comment: Despite emphasising the importance of naming, why is there `i`, `j` and `values` in the *Fixed alternative*s? Why is the more readable list comprehension not taking place in your snippet where the unpythonic "[]-for-append" idiom is employed?

Comment: @Neither Well observed my focus here! (a) Left the advice as bonus, but focused on _minimal-invasive_ fixing. __improved naming requires contextual semantics__ to be clarified first (e.g. is `i` an `inner_list` or rather `scored_groups` contains people = names with scores. (b) Readability is subjective: _list-comprehension_ is a _Pythonic idiom_. As such it's comprehensible to advanced Pythonistas. Most code-readers can understand the __polyglot for-loops__. So I adapted to the audience's skill-level and re-used `[]-for-append` (what a great term ️) to build upon OP's known patterns. ️

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to check if a key of the inner dictionary in `mod` matches the key in the replacement dict, that's an issue.

A list comprehension with a dict comprehension does the result:

```
>>> [{result_dict1[key]: value for key, value in inner_dict.items()}
     for inner_dict in mod]

[{'Nikhil': 1, 'Vashu': 5, 'Manjeet': 10, 'Akshat': 15},
 {'Nikhil': 1, 'Vashu': 5, 'Manjeet': 10, 'Akshat': 15}]
```

So the dict comprehension is changing the inner dicitionaries of the `mod` such that the keys are replaced from `result_dict1`. The list comprehension helps do this for every inner dictionary.

This will err if `result_dict1` isn't comprehensive enough.

---

The comprehensions above can be unwrapped as

```
# this is the final result; we'll fill in this
end_list = []

# foreach dictionary in `mod`...
for inner_dict in mod:
    # define anew empty dict
    new_inner_dict = {}
    
    # foreach (key, val) pair of the `inner_dict`...
    for key, value in inner_dict.items():
        # get the `new_key` from the replacer mapping
        new_key = result_dict1[key]
        
        # put it into the new dict (but the value is the same)
        new_inner_dict[new_key] = value

    # above for ended, we have a new_inner_dict; save it
    end_list.append(new_inner_dict)

print(end_list)
```

Comment: Cool. Understood brother.  I didn't get the for loop part in the code. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: @whatsinthename You mean in your code or in this code?

Comment: and please don't assume gender, thanks.

Comment: I meant In your code

Comment: @whatsinthename I wrote an equivalent for loop version of the comprehension hoping it helps. Two codes are ~equivalent.

Comment: Yeah. Understood. Thanks for your help :)